# WCF Service - certificates and message security with UserName authentication

Tags: .net, authentication, wcf, certificate

I'm preparing to create a WCF Service which our customers can use to update data in our system. So it has to be available over the Internet. I have a book about WCF from which I know the `Message Security` is the way to go when making a WCF Service available over the Internet. That is because you shouldn't use the transport security because it should only be used in environments where you can guarantee that there is a point-to-point connection between service and client. Did I get that right?
So I want to use Message Security in combination with a custom `UserName` authentication. I understand that I have to get a certificate to accomplish that. Our company already owns a SSL Certificate that is used for our Websites.

- **Can I use the same certificate for the message security of the WCF Service?**

And

- **Is the Message Security way interoperable with clients that expect a ASMX Webservice?**

For testing purposes I created my own certificate with Makecert. It worked fine but I always had to add the certificate to the `Trusted Persons` on the client machine.

- **Is it possible to enable the `Message Security` with the above mentioned certificate without forcing the client to add the certificate to the `Trusted Persons` manually?**

Now, let's assume the following scenario:

[image: Company Infrastructure]

There are two Webservers behind an ISA-Server/Firewall. This ISA-Server holds the certificate for the www.company.com address. So all the SSL stuff is handled by it. It also forwards the incoming requests to the webservers accordingly. The newly created WCF Service should run on the 2nd webserver.

- **Do I have to copy the certificate to the webserver to be able to use the `Message Security`?**

If yes, I heard copying certificates is not good practice because it reduces the level of security. Moving the certificate to the webserver is not an option, because it's needed for the websites on Web-Server1, too.

- **What are my options in this case?**

And:

- **What would be the best practice for this scenario, regardless of the given requirements?**

Thank you...

Comment: In the question you mention that you would like to use Message security with UserName authentication, then I am not sure why copying the certificates is required for Message Security? What I am missing?

Comment: When using MessageSecurity your messages can be signed and/or encrypted. Therefore you need a private key of a certificate and the other part needs the public key. If the server that hosts the WCF Service does not have the private key how should he be able to sign or encrypt the message? Or decrypt incomming messages for that matter. Message security only includes the security context in itsself so you do not have to rely on the capabilities of your transport. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733137.aspx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nicely prepared question. First of all I probably read the same book and I would like to clarify this statement:

> That is because you shouldn't use the
>   transport security because it should
>   only be used in environments where you
>   can guarantee that there is a
>   point-to-point connection between
>   service and client.

Yes. HTTPS (transport security) offers only point-to-point security but IMO people don't understand this scenario correctly. Do you think that if you connect to your Internet banking over HTTPs it will randomly somewhere in the middle of Internet swap communication from HTTPS to HTTP? NO! Point-to-point connection means secured transport channel between client and accessed gateway providing the requested URL. In your scenario it means secured transport channel between Client and your ISA Server. Communication will not be secured between your ISA and Web Server 2. If you want end-to-end which will provide secure channel between client and Web Server 2 (ISA will not be able to intercept messages), you need message security.

Now to your other questions:

> Can I use the same certificate for the
>   message security of the WCF Service?

Yes you can, but you have to copy private key to your Web Server 2.

> Is the Message Security way
>   interoperable with clients that expect
>   a ASMX Webservice?

No. Pure ASMX client can't use message security unless you code a lot of custom SOAP headers and extensions or install WSE 3.0.

> Is it possible to enable the Message
>   Security with the above mentioned
>   certificate without forcing the client
>   to add the certificate to the Trusted
>   Persons manually?

Yes but Certification authority which published certificate must be trusted on client machine. It is same with HTTPS. Services secured with message security also can expose certificate's thumbprint inside WSDL. Clients can validate service identity with this thumbprint. I think that in such case you also don't need to install certificate on client but when certificate expires all clients will have to be updated.

> Do I have to copy the certificate to
>   the webserver to be able to use the
>   Message Security?

Yes you must. But this can be a problem because for security reason's certificate can be marked as not exportable. Best solution is to request new certificate just for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. :-) What's your suggestion? Switch to transport security? If yes how do I tell the service, that the ISA is in charge of handling transport security? Because if I set the transport security mode, the service also requires a certificate present on the 'web-server2', doesn't it? Can I still use the userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" or is this only possible with the message security setting? So many questions ... ;)

Comment: Yes all these requirements are possible. It is just your choice based on requirements and confidentality of transported data.

Comment: Nice clarification on the misinterpretation of what Point-to-Point security means. I've been reading around to understand the best way to develop a WCF to be consumed in PHP and was afraid `basicHTTPBinding` over HTTPS was not secure.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka: Isn't that the other reason we want message security so that we can authenticate the client connecting to the service? Otherwise if we only had Transport, then potentially any client can connect to the service? Am I missing something here? 
Also, In the question OP mention that they would like to use Message security with UserName authentication, then I am not sure why copying the certificates is required for Message Security? What I am missing? Thanks.

Comment: @VoodooChild: Yes you can use client certificate in SOAP header to authenticate the client. It is not "full" message security because there will be no encryption on message level. Copying certificate was related to full message security where server needs to perform encryption and it needs certificate (to work correctly behind firewall load balanced machines should use same certificate).

Comment: You wrote `Communication will not be secured between your ISA and Web Server 2` - but that's his internal network, so why should he care if it's not secured there (assuming he trusts his own company network)? After reading your clarification I began to think maybe transport should be enough over the internet because it's secured all the way until the server's network (which we trust). What am I missing here?

Comment: @BornToCode: Most attacks come from internal network and usually even if you have transport security, you will have another transport security channel in your internal network so decrypted content will be only on the publicly facing server and destination.