# Using digital certificates for message and transport security in WCF web services

Tags: web-services, wcf, ssl, digital-certificate

With a WCF web service, do both message and transport security require a digital certificate to be installed on the server? Does that certificate need to be "CA" issued or can I generate one myself?  And finally, can the same certificate be used for both message and transport security?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679235/wcf-service-certificates-and-message-security-with-username-authentication

Answer (score 0):

I purchased a GeoTrust SSL certificate for my domain and with this one certificate, I was successfully able to get all of Transport security, Message security and TransportWithMessageCredential security to work.

With Message and TransportWithMessageCredential security, I am using MessageCredentialType = UserName.